Summing up values of polygons within bigger polygon in QGIS
I have buildings as polygons with a lot of data in the attribute table. My goal is, to sum up the values selected for a table column of all building polygons within the building blocks (here in purple).
So if I have three buildings with their values in my column of interest (50,100, 150), the (new) building block is supposed to get the value 300.
How can I do this in QGIS?


If you want to sum up all the buildings within a building block look at the Overlap Analysis tool.  You can also look at the Overlay tools or Join Attributes by Location.  If you use the overlay you can use the GDAL dissolve tool and set how it handles numerical data, or you can use the Group Stats plugin, or you can export your data for use in a pivot table.  It looks like you have selected some of the buildings in a block but I'm not sure how that factors in to your question.

Isn’t the sum of 50, 100 and 150 not 200 but 300?

You can use Expressions.
I have two layers:

Neighboorhod
Building

I want to summarize the Building attribute population for all buildings whose point_on_surface is within each neighborhood.
Expression:
aggregate(layer:='Building', aggregate:='sum', expression:="population", filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), point_on_surface($geometry)))
I use it to label, you can also use it in Field Calculator if you want to create a column.

